# How can I awk lines that contain a certain value & above in a log?

Tags: awk

I have a few logs that I am trying to filter. The log contains an IP & UID at the end. I would like to only copy the lines with the specific UID value and anything above that value.

Log:

```
1.2.4.5 1000
5.4.3.2 2000
7.4.2.1 1000
1.3.5.2 5000
```

For example I would only like to copy the lines containing any value above 2000,  and move it into a separate file. I have tried many awk commands I have found with no luck.

```
awk -F: '{if ($3 > 2000) { print $1 ":" $3 } }' log.txt > newlog.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'no luck'? `$3` with the example input would be blank. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You also have set the field separator to `:` but your example input does not have any `:` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works and adds your wanted colon separator:

```
awk '$2>2000' < log.txt | awk '{print $1 ":" $2}' > newlog.txt
```

newlog.txt outputs

> 1.3.5.2:5000

Answer (score 0):

As a filter, all you need is the test. The truth or falsity of the test will cause filtering by printing on true.

Example:

```
$ echo "1.2.4.5 1000
5.4.3.2 2000
7.4.2.1 1000
1.3.5.2 5000" | awk '$2>2000'
1.3.5.2 5000
```